# Html code to scroll to a section in a webpage when a button is pressed

Tags: html, css, scroll, elementor

Ok I have no programming experience but I am currently working within Elementor, a website building tool and on my site, I have an Html tag that creates a button named South America:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction_sa()">
  South America
</button>
```

There is also another Html tag that contains a script. This script unhides the section "sam-sec" when the button "South America" is pressed. The script goes:

```js
<script>
function myFunction_sa() {
  var x = document.getElementById("sam-sec");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

The section "sam-sec" is hidden by default. I would like to add a function so that when the button "South America" is pressed, and the section has been made visible, the window automatically scrolls to that section.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

1. Delegate and give a data attribute
2. use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)
3. toggle class instead of using style.display

The dummy div is just for spacing reasons during test

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target
    if (tgt.classList.contains("scrollAndShow")) {
      const id = tgt.dataset.id;
      const div = document.getElementById(id);
      if (div) {
        div.classList.toggle("hide")
        if (!div.classList.contains("hide")) div.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}

.dummy { display:block; height:500px }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <button type="button" class="scrollAndShow" data-id="sam-sec">South America</button>
  <button type="button" class="scrollAndShow" data-id="eur-sec">Europe</button>
</div>
<div class="dummy"><hr/></div>
<div id="sam-sec" class="hide">South America</div>
<div class="dummy"><hr/></div>
<div id="eur-sec" class="hide">Europe</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And for a smooth scroll, try this:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction_sa()">
  South America
</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="sam-sec" class="hidden">South America</div>

<script>
  function myFunction_sa() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sam-sec");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.classList.add('hidden');

    } else {
      x.classList.remove('hidden');; // You wanted it visible prior to scroll so this comes first  
      x.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
      }); // added '{behavior: 'smooth'}' for smooth scroll
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    scroll-behaviour: smooth;
}
```

```html
<a href="#SA"><button>South America</button></a>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br>
<h2 id="SA">South America</h2>
```

Easy